# What's the color of Scaffold background?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
    child: Scaffold(),
  );
}
```

[image]

I see black background behind my `Scaffold`, obviously this isn't `Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor` because both light and dark theme show same white color. So, what color is it?

Comment: By default Scaffold has white background color

Comment: Default color is `Color(0xfffafafa)` according to `scaffoldBackgroundColor`

Comment: @Diwyansh It shows black not white, and second the area behind `Scaffold` isn't a `Scaffold`.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh But that's not a `scaffoldBackgroundColor` because it is black which is a `#000000`

Comment: @iDecode I'm not talking about behind Scaffold I have simply said that the background color of Scaffold is white and behind the Scaffold the color is dark.

Comment: @Diwyansh So, the question is where that black color is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

There is no property to define that color inside ThemeData.
You can check at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

As you say, the property scaffoldBackgroundColor is just the color of the Material widget that underlies the entire Scaffold.

But if you want a color or maybe a gradient behind your Scaffold, you can use container.

Solid Color

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Scaffold(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

---

Linear Gradient

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white70),
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blue.shade600, Colors.blue.shade900],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Scaffold(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found
the default background color of scaffold comes from `backgroundColor` which comes from `ThemeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor`

If we don't define `scaffoldBackgroundColor` it comes from  `canvasColor`

`scaffoldBackgroundColor ??= canvasColor;`

And the canvas color is defined on [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/90b18fc5f0002e380a361b0f91a5cf7039982d4b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart#L455)  like

`canvasColor ??= isDark ? Colors.grey[850]! : Colors.grey[50]!;`

Therefore, the default color of `scaffoldBackgroundColor` is **`Colors.grey[50]`**

The black is coming because of `Padding`.

Comment: I already know the default background color of `Scaffold` which is definitely not black, and you said the black is coming from `Padding`, are you sure because if I wrap `Padding` in a `ColoredBox` and give white color to it, then the Padding will start showing white instead of black. So, the question is (according to what you wrote), where that black is coming from in `Padding`?

Comment: Padding used to constrained its child and fill the remaining space with nothing, and we can see the ancestor color. While `scaffold` itself is the child, we can see black background. By wrapping `ColoredBox` padding, empty spaces fill with it. The existence of black also becomes clear using `home: Center(
            child: Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.green)))`

Comment: Where that ancestor color (the black) is coming from, this is the question.

Comment: My theory is: there is nothing and that's why it is black[default color]

Answer (score 0):

Here when you use Padding or anyother widget as parent on the screen, then you have the background color from the theme or from the MaterialApp initial widget from main.dart file.

If you need any specific color on this single screen alone. then,

1. Use scaffold as parent and apply background color. Use padding as its direct child.
2. Wrap with Theme widget to the Padding widget

Comment: "then you have the background color from the theme" -- what color is that, this is the question.